# CSOM Set Sharing on OneDrive Folder

Tags: c#, permissions, onedrive, csom

I'd like to set sharing rights on a folder in OneDrive.  I know there is a post out there about ListItems, but I need it at a folder level.  First, is this possible or am I wasting my time?  I've tried the following:

I'm able to get the site object but I'm not able to get the folder in order to share it.  The web object doesn't have the folders available to enumerate through.  It says it's not initialized.  This code below successfully runs but the folder object is not working:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webUrl = "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/me_tenant_com";
        var userName = "me";
        string securePassword = "mypassword";
        SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
        Array.ForEach(securePassword.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);

        using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, sec_pass);

            var web = ctx.Web;
            ClientResult<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalInfo> persons = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ResolvePrincipal(ctx, ctx.Web, "dpunchak@AvvenireInc.com", Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All, null, true);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/documents/Test Folder");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalInfo person = persons.Value;

            //ShareListItem(folder, person, "Read");
        }
    }

    public static void ShareListItem(ListItem listItem, Principal principal, string permissionLevelName)
    {
        var ctx = listItem.Context as ClientContext;
        var roleDefinition = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByName(permissionLevelName);
        listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
        var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { roleDefinition };
        listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(principal, roleBindings);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to pass [`folder.ListItemAllFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields.aspx) property to `ShareListItem()`.

To avoid *collection has not been initialized* error you can try placing `RoleAssignments.Add()` inside `ctx.ExecuteQuery()`:

```
ctx.ExecuteQuery(listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(principal, roleBindings);
```